# jQuery bind click event to button on each option of select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, each

I'm trying to make a click event on submit button on each option element of select.

Here is my script:

```
var selectObj = $("#selectObj");

selectObj.find("option").each(function(){
    selectObj.val($(this).val());
    $("#submitBtn").click();
});
```

But, it just work on the last option element.

Comment: As I understand your comment to Ashay Mandwarya's answer, what you are trying to achieve is the following: If the user selects any element in your list, you want to select all elements and immediately submit the form. Right? Could you perhaps elaborate a bit, why you are trying to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, it just work on the last option element.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but your code should work.

Also not sure about the usage of `selectObj.val($(this).val());`

```js
var selectObj = $("#selectObj");

selectObj.find("option").each(function(){
    //selectObj.val($(this).val());
    $("#submitBtn").click(myFunc($(this).val()));
});

function myFunc(val){
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectObj">
  <option value="first">First</option>
  <option value="second">Second</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="submitBtn" >Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value will be set to the element on `change` event.

```js
var select;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#s > option').each( function(e){
select=$('#s > option')[e].innerHTML
a(select);
})
function a(val)
{
$('button').trigger('click');
console.log('The values is ' +val)
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s"><option>a</option>
<option>d</option><option>b</option>
<option>e</option><option>c</option></select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Sorry for being late. I'm trying to make the script automatically select all options and send click event on each option.